# Short-circuiting a condition statement

Tags: python

I wrote a function:

```
# given a n x m grid return how many different ways there are to move from top left to 
# bottom right by only being able to move right or down

def grid(n, m, memo = {}):
    if f'{n},{m}' in memo:
        return memo[f'{n},{m}']

    if n == 1 and m == 1:
        return 1
    
    if n == 0 or m == 0:
        return 0

    memo[f'{n},{m}'] = grid(n,m-1,) + grid(n-1,m)

    return grid(n,m-1,) + grid(n-1,m)
```

Recently I read a bit about short-circuiting in Python and I am trying to understand it further.

As I understand it does not provide any boost in runtime, just sort of syntax sugar.

For example:

```
1 < 2 < 3 # is True
1 < 2 and 2 < 3 # is also True

# hence
(1 < 2 < 3) == 1 < 2 and 2 < 3 # is True
```

I was wondering can I write my function with this kind of short-circuiting in my `if` statements?

I came up with this:

```
 def grid(n, m, memo = {}):
    if f'{n},{m}' in memo:
        return memo[f'{n},{m}']

    if (n or m) == 1:
        return 1
    
    if (n and m) == 0:
        return 0

    memo[f'{n},{m}'] = grid(n,m-1,) + grid(n-1,m)

    return grid(n,m-1,) + grid(n-1,m)
```

Is there any smarter way of using the short-circuit here?

Comment: `if (n or m) == 1` is definitely *not* the same thing as `if n == 1 or m == 1`.

Comment: So how would this be written in such fashion: is n or m equal to 1? Without using `n == 1 or m == 1`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: The and test: `if n == 1 and m == 1:` can be converted to `if n == m == 1:`.

Comment: `1 < 2 < 3` is not [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short-circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not), it's actually [chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=chained#index-78), which is sort of the opposite in some respects.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (n or m) == 1` is definitely not the same thing as `if n == 1 or m == 1`. The first `if` statement is equivalent to:

```
value = n
if not value:
    value = m
if value == 1:
    # do something:
```

Or expressed more succinctly:

```
if (n if n else m) == 1:
       # do something
```

In other words, `n or m` only evaluates `m` if `n` is False (or 0 if `n` is an integer), otherwise the result of the expression is `n`.

What you want to avoid redundancy is:

```
if 1 in (n, m): # equivalent to: if 1 is either n or m:
```

**Update:** Demo

```
n = 4
m = 1
if (n or m) == 1:
    print('if branch taken')
else:
    print('else branch taken')
```

Prints:

```
else branch taken
```

Comment: I believed I used `(n or m) == 1` correct in my case, isnt this the same as `If either n or m is 1: do something`. Because  both `(1 or 0) ` and `(0 and 1)` return `1` which I after compare to `1`?

Comment: I am talking about the general case for arbitrary values n and m. If you know the values of n and m, why bother even having an if statement? Then the whole question becomes rather pointless.

Comment: Equivalently, `if n == 1 and m == 1:` can be `if (m, n) == (1, 1):` (or `m == n == 1`...)

Comment: As `m` and `n` can only be integers and I only care if any of those are 1, if so, return 1. So `if (n or m) == 1: return 1` returns me 1 if either `m` or `n` is 1 which is what I need. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think I would prefer `if n == 1 == m:`, which avoids creating a tuple.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis If n is 4 and m is 1 then `(n or m)` evaluates to `4` which will *not* be equal to `1` and the if expression will evaluate to `False`. You are definitely missing something. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 3):

`(1 < 2 < 3)` is not short-circuiting - I think you misunderstood the meaning of the term. You are correct that it is merely syntax sugar - although it can produce some very weird results in obscure cases. `(1 < 2 < 3)` expands to `(1 < 2) and (2 < 3)` - the middle operand is copied to both and `and` is used for the joining operator.

Short circuiting occurs when python *already knows* the answer to a boolean expression, even before calculating both the inputs. For example

```py
def false():
    print("false")
    return False

def true():
    print("true")
    return True

print(false() and true())
```

The output would be

```
false
False
```

Because when python sees `False and`, it already knows that the result is `False` (because `and` requires both operands to be `True`), so it doesn't bother running the second half of the line.
This real short circuiting *does* result in a performance boost, but since you can't turn off short circuiting, it doesn't really matter ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You are contradicting yourself... `(1 < 2 < 3)` expands to `(1 < 2) and (2 < 3)` so ***there is short-circuiting***... If `1 < 2`, then `2 < 3` will not be evaluated at all... And also - from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons): *"`x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that __`y` is evaluated only once__ (but in both cases __`z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false__"* - so there is your improvement, not *merely syntax sugar*...

Comment: Ok that's fair. I did read it, a few weeks ago, but I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n or m) == 1
```

evaluates to

```
if (<bool>) == 1  # e.g. if {True,False} == 1
```

which is probably not what you want, since it is essentially evaluating the truthiness of `n` or `m`.

Your existing code [**already captures the nature of short-circuiting**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not);

```
if n == 1 and m == 1
```

will only evaluate the second argument `m == 1` *iff* `n == 1`, or will otherwise short-circuit.

To your comment

> As I understand it does not provide any boost in runtime, just sort of syntax suggar.

Well, actually it does provide a runtime boost if Python is able to skip evaluating what would otherwise be "expensive" conditions to evaluate because it is able to short-circuit early.